# Erroneous query from backup script results in error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code is a minimal example from a larger query generated by a backup script (possibly using `mysqldump`). It results in an error and I don't know why. Who can help?

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_custom_tandem_lang` (
    `id` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
);
```

Produces following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(`id`),   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) )' at line 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `PRIMARY KEY` not `PRIMARY_KEY` (*remove the underscore to make it work.*)

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_custom_tandem_lang` 
(
    `id` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `tb_unique` (`id`)
);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4be55)

Answer (score 0):

remove the 'id' after UNIQUE KEY like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_custom_tandem_lang` (
    `id` varchar(2) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Why should I do that? I think it makes the key a named one so I can reference it later on, doesn't it?